# potentially a memory leak - how should I fix this

Tags: angular

My Angular application received response from server in JSON format. I convert the response into a model like follows

```js
let questionListSubscription = this.questionManagementService.questionsArray$.subscribe((result: Result) => {
        console.log("received result from question array observable", result);
        if (result.result === "success") {
            //received response from server
            let questionList = JSON.parse(result.additionalInfo) as PracticeQuestionsListAPI;
            console.log("got list of questions value ", questionList);
            //...
            this.questionsFilter["pagination-info"] = questionList["pagination-info"];
            //...
        }
    }
);
```

The above randomly crashed with error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pagination-info' of undefined` pointing to line `this.questionsFilter['pagination-info'] = questionList['pagination-info'];`

When I ran the code again, it worked.

Is the above assignment wrong and could potentially lead to memory leak?

Comment: When is the field/property `questionsFilter` set? Is it also done in a call back that executes concurrently with the call back to `questionsArray`? If so you have a race condition and you must chain your observables so that the callbacks execute in a specific order. Also this has nothing to do with a memory leak, that is a completely unrelated topic (google it to see what that entails).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not defined the `this.questionsFilter` correctly. It should be defined as:

```
questionsFilter = {}
```

Comment: In `Angular6`, I have defined it as `export class PraticeQuestionListComponent implements OnInit {questionsFilter:GetQuestionsfilter ; }`. Now I have also initialised it as `this.questionsFilter = new GetQuestionsfilter("",new AdditionalPagingInfo("",new PartitionInfo(0,0)));` in constructor. I am wondering is just assigning it to the incoming response is incorrect in some way

Comment: Then check if the questionList['pagination-info']; is getting the value from API